# How do I call 2 ids using document.getElementById on 1 click

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is how I am trying to call 2 ids i.e modal-wrapper and close-wrapper using only 1 onclick - but I don't know how to do it:

```
 <button onclick="document.getElementById('modal-wrapper','close-wrapper').style.display='block'">SIGN UP</button>

 <script>
 var close = document.getElementById('close-wrapper');
 window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == close) {
        close.style.display = "none";
    }
 }
 </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You might find it easier to use classes in your HTML.

In this example I've separated out the inline JS.

I've added classes to the wrappers and the button. I've also added a "hidden" class to each wrapper which sets its display to "none".

```js
// Pick up the button
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector
const signup = document.querySelector('.signup');

// Add an event listener to it
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener
signup.addEventListener('click', handleSignup, false);

function handleSignup() {

  // Pick up the wrappers by class
  // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll
  const wrappers = document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper');

  // For each wrapper remove the hidden class
  // https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList
  wrappers.forEach(wrapper => wrapper.classList.remove('hidden'));
}
```

```css
.hidden { display: none; }
```

```html
<button class="signup">SIGN UP</button>
<div class="wrapper hidden">Modal wrapper</div>
<div class="wrapper hidden">Close wrapper</div>
```